# List (exhaustive-ish) of predicates with “quirky subject”? (“Lexikalischer Kasus”)

Tags: verb

I’m trying to find an exhaustive-ish list of predicates with [quirky subjects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirky_subject) ([Lexikalischer Kasus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexikalischer_Kasus)) to get a better idea of how many of these there are (a dozen, a hundred?), how common they are, and whether there is any sort of sub-type structure.

An object is called *a quirky subject* if it is an object only grammatically due to a predicate having a ”quirky“ grammatical behaviour and, weren’t it for these grammatical specialities, you would make it the subject of the sentence. Such predicates don’t take a nominative complement (or at least resist it, at least for some speakers). For example:

> Mir ist kalt.
> <s>Es ist mir kalt.</s>
>
> Mich friert.
> <s>Es friert mich.</s>

Non-quirky:

> Ich friere.

Comment: `Mich friert.` is outdated. Apart from `ich friere`, it's more common to say `Mich friert es.`, which has a subject.

Comment: Mir ist [warm/kalt/langweilig/schlecht]. And most transfer-verbs in passive : Mir wird [gegeben/geschrieben/geschenkt]....

Comment: Do you want us to contribute to or provide source links to such a list?

Comment: @dervonnebenaan Hm, I was just wondering if anyone had already made such a list. Although if they haven't, I guess we could turn this into a wiki-post (I know that's a stackexchange feature; don't know anything bout the details tho) and people could contribute to making a list.

Comment: »Mich friert.« I wouldn't call that outdated. It is excellent German, bit high-level maybe. »Mir ist kalt.« That's the  most common, at least in Norddeutschland.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some words that could match your search. Some of them seem to be outdated or  aristocratic (at least when they are used without a subject). But maybe this small list can help you to look for more of such words...

> mich friert, mich dürstet, mich hungert, mich schwitzt, mich
>   schläfert, mich reuet, mich schaudert, mir graut, mir ekelt, mich
>   dünkt, mich deucht, mir schwant, mir schwindelt, mich verlangt, mich
>   gelüstet, mich schmerzt, mich wundert